# Calculating IT Spend Ratio

Tags: finance, financial-economics, corporate-finance

I have three columns - Sales(Revenue), Employee Count and Industry of n Companies in my sheet, how do I use them to calculate the IT Spend Ratio of these companies using the above info?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! It seems like you are asking for something impossible. E.g., if I tell you my height, income and occupaion you will not be able to glean know much I spent on yogurts (or IT) last month.